# Multiple conditions in for loop statement

Tags: c

```
for (icnt = 1; icnt <= (ino1 / 2) && (ino2 / 2) ; icnt++)
```

and

```
for (icnt = 1; icnt <= (ino1 / 2) && icnt <= (ino2 / 2) ; icnt++)
```

Both `for` loops gives same output still then what is the difference between both statements ? I tried to find out flow of program, can someone explain me what is the difference

Comment: `(ino2 / 2)` is equivalent to `0 != (ino2 / 2)`. `0 != (ino2 / 2)` is not equivalent to `icnt <= (ino2 / 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both loops iterate the same number of times only by chance, probably because `ino1 <= ino2`.

The first loop iterates while `icnt <= ino1 / 2` **and** `ino2 / 2 != 0`, which is very different from the second loop condition where `icnt` must be less or equal to **both** `ino1 / 2` and `ino2 / 2`.